# Is there clue yet regarding the Magento2 solution specialist exam passing score, questions, and is there anyone who has given this exam yet?

Tags: magento2, certification

I have been **registered** for **Magento2** solution **specialist exam**. As **Magento** has not revealed anything regarding the **passing score** as it normally does for other **exams**, I have few **questions** regarding it, listing them below.

1. Is any one who has given this exam yet? If yes, need your valuable
   input.
2. Is there any clue regarding the passing mark?
3. Is there any clue regarding the real questions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi.Passing score and criteria is still not known. May be based on the 200 registrants they will decide some cut-off. I have also not came across any person who gave the exam. I have also registered for the same and looking for some blogs . Thanks

Comment: @AhmadVaqasKhan Seems so, still looking for some exact answers. A lot of confusion in this exam :)